# Key not gettiing sent to background window ControlSend

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to send f keys to a backgrounded game while I browse the web. The script runs and doesn't error out

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.


toggle = 0
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2

F8::
    Toggle := !Toggle
     While Toggle{
        ControlSend [f,Entropia.exe]
            }
return
```

IF I run this , activate the toggle, and press f with entropia opened and say notepad as the focus the Fs are showing up in notepad and not being sent to entropia

Comment: Try `ControlSend,, [f, ahk_exe Entropia.exe`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use AHK to send keys to a background window (just like you can't type on your keyboard into a background window).

Best you can do is quickly switch over to the window (you don't have to show the window or bring it forward, just activate it briefly) **then** send the key and **then** switch back to your current window.